# Нужен совет по потокам, привязка потока к итему в Listview

Tags: listview, delphi, потоки-данных

В своей программе делаю мини менеджер загрузок, и раньше в одном потоке работал отлично, но появилась необходимость создать многопоточный менеджер. Потоки работают исправно, создаются, качают и завершаются, меняя статус закачки. Но столкнулся с проблемой: при создании потока я делал привязку его к индексу элемента в Listview (знаю что это плохо, но другого я на тот момент не нашел) и сейчас при удалении итема, индексация срывается (при скачивании показывается выполненный процент в том итеме, который качается). Думал на счет поиска по заранее назначеному идентификатору, но надеюсь, что есть более простой способ, т.к. читал про привязку объектов в Listbox-е. Может что посоветуете буду очень благодарен. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще в приложении не рекомендовано использовать более 16 потоков. Это рекомендация Microsoft. Так, что подумайте над тем, если пользователь недалекий, то он будет загружать более 16 файлов одновременно. Это во первых будет очень сильно грузить систему(оочень сильно), во вторых потребуется сложная синхронизация потоков. Поэтому, я вам искренне рекомендую переработать движок менеджера.

Comment: А если делать ограничения на количество одновременных загрузок как это сделано в DMaster?? А с привязкой разобрался, все оказывается делается через ListView.Data и указатели в самом типе. Спасибо за рекомендацию, сейчас подумаю, что можно сделать...

Comment: Люди не любят ограничения...по себе знаю =)

Comment: А что тогда можете посоветовать??

Comment: Delphi знаю давно, знаком с ним очень хорошо. С потоками также приходилось и приходится работать очень часто. Поэтому, я бы вам советовал аоздать в программе всего один дополнительный поток, который будет загружать файлы. Если пользователь начнет скачивать новый файл, то, например, в массив скачиваемых файлов будет добавляться новое имя файла, ну а поток уже будет читать этот массиви загружать файлы. Вот так.

Comment: все гениальное просто! что-то я до этого не дошел) спасибо большое!